# Changing colour of data points according to interaction term using plot_model

Tags: r, ggplot2, interaction, geom-point, marginal-effects

Im currently running a Random Intercept Model in which I am regressing the average change in welfare depending on the preferences of the richest 5 percent on the income population in various countries and interacting this with how financially globalised a specific countries are.

I am able to plot the actual data on to my plot, however whenever i try to colour the data for various levels of financial globalisation, R gives me the output:

```
'Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale'
```

This is even though my 'financial globalisation' variable is a numeric class and continous.

This is the model:

```r
model <- lmer(dgentav14 ~ p95*Financial_Open_Logged + gent +
                loggdpt + growtht + unempt + factor(topic) + 
                factor(wave) + (1 | country), 
              data = data_master1, 
              REML = FALSE)
```

And this is how I have tried to plot the the actual data given the levels of financial openness onto the plot:

```r
plot_model(model, 
           type = "int", 
           terms = c("p95", "Financial_Open_Logged"), 
           show.data = FALSE) + 
           geom_point(data = data_master1, 
                      aes(x = p95, 
                          y = dgentav14, 
                          colour = 'Financial_Open_Logged'),  
                      inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_color_continuous()
```

Lastly: This is what I get back from R:

```r
Scale for colour is already present.
Adding another scale for colour, which will replace the existing scale.
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `plot_model()` turns the conditioning variable values into a factor for the purposes of plotting and then colours the lines and ribbons by that factor variable (i.e., makes a discrete color scale).  In the package `ggnewscale` there is an option for generating new color scales that can live along side existing ones.  Here's an example:

```r
data(Duncan, package="carData")
library(ggplot2)
library(sjPlot)
library(ggnewscale)
library(lme4)
library(dplyr)
m <- lmer(prestige ~ income*education + (1|type), data=Duncan)
plot_model(m, 
           type = "int", 
           terms = c("income", "education"), 
           show.data = FALSE) + 
  labs(color="Education\nCondition") + 
  new_scale_color() + 
  geom_point(data = Duncan %>% rename(ed_data = education), 
             aes(x = income, 
                 y = prestige , 
                 colour = ed_data),  
             inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_color_continuous(name="Education\nData\nValues")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>